# How to hide some sub-menu items

Tags: dm-script

all:

I have create a menu with 5 sub-menus. But in some case, I only would like to display 3 of these sub-meunus. Besides generating a new menu, is that possible to use some flag to display the needed sub-menus?

Regards

Chen ZX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menu objects in DM do not have "flag" properties that determine whether menu items are visible. A better way to think of a Menu object is as a globally accessible resource that can be dynamically altered in response to events that occur within the DM app. In other words, when conditions are such that you want the sub-menu visibility to change (which you must detect either via an event or some test done by a periodically executed script), then you need to get a reference to the affected menu object and add the desired sub-menus via the AddMenuItem method or remove them via the RemoveMenuItem method.

Another approach is to simply disable the sub-menus by using the SetIsEnabled method on them. Although this does not remove the sub-menus, it does gray them out and prevents any code connected to them from being triggered through user actions.

Details about the script interface to DM's menus are provided in the on-line help at the path Scripting > Objects > Menus.